# Passing data between threads, all can produce, all should consume (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a broadcast server where all clients should be able to send a broadcast message to all clients, and all clients should receive a broadcast from any client. I'm trying to figure out what the best way would be to implement this on the server side. I've run across a `BlockingQueue`, but my understanding is that when one thread calls `take()`, it removes the item so that the other threads can't get the data, and that each client is either a producer or a consumer. What would the best way be to implement this? Each client will have a thread on the server side.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Producer/Consumer threads using a Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332537/producer-consumer-threads-using-a-queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of pub-sub mechanism. This is hard to implement in Java from the bottom up. I recommend you look at some existing implementation.

For a simple, non persistent solution you should check out the [Guava EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained). Spring has something like an event bus according to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663988/what-kind-of-eventbus-to-use-in-spring-built-in-reactor-akka), although I can't find more docs. Finally you can check out the [Akka event bus](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/event-bus.html) if you're feeling adventurous.

For a persistent solution you could use a JMS provider (like ActiveMQ) and the topic/subscriber pattern. I've had very good experiences with Spring + JMS. Redis can also do pub/sub (not a JMS implementation!) and it has the advantage of being distributed. I've never tried it so I don't know how good it is.

Answer (score 0):

Give each client a thread-safe queue, and insert sent all messages into *every* queue.

When no client needs a message any more, it will be automatically garbage collected.

Comment: After writing that, it seems really inefficient.  I guess that's what you get when using broadcast messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky subject and I really do not recommend rolling your own. Use [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) instead. These people work on this all day long and know what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for kryonet project. I'm using it in my few projects and it's realy good